# Hibernate - rewrite legacy createCriteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a following Hibernate code:

```
        return (Post)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Post.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("title", title))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("description", description))
                .uniqueResult();
```

But the method `createCriteria` is deprecated. How to rewrite it to `CriteriaQuery` so the code remains minimalistic and without the use of `CriteriaBuilder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hibernate 5.4](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createCriteria-java.lang.String-) docs recommend usage of Jakarta Persistence API (JPA) classes under `javax.persistence.criteria` package wherever we were using Hibernate's `SharedSessionContract.createCriteria(java.lang.Class)` method. In fact all the methods including the overloads of the method `createCriteria` that returned `org.hibernate.Criteria` are deprecated, which indirectly means that Hibernate doesn't want us to use their `org.hibernate.Criteria` interface anymore. In version 5.4, there is no implementing class or extending interface for the `Criteria` interface. In short, the hibernate `Session` that used to act as a factory for `Criteria` objects no longer produces them and `Criteria` might be fully deprecated in future versions.

Secondly, Hibernate offered useful API under the package `org.hibernate.criterion` e.g. Restrictions, Example, etc. The problem is that all of these classes seem to have only one consumer class of type `org.hibernate.Criteria` which is being deprecated. In other words, if you can't use `org.hibernate.Criteria`, you can't use `org.hibernate.criteria.Restrictions` either.

In summary, if you have to refactor your above code now, your only choice is what you have under `javax.persistence.criteria`. Therefore, your only choice is to use `CriteriaBuilder` and `CreateQuery` as shown below.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();

// Create query
CriteriaQuery<Post> q = cb.createQuery(Post.class)
Root<Post> r = q.from(Post.class);

Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[2];
predicates[0] = cb.equal(root.get("title"), title);
predicates[1] = cb.equal(root.get("description"), description);

q.select(r).where(predicates);
Query<Post> query = session.createQuery(q);
return query.getSingleResult();
```

Yes, this code is quite verbose compared to your original code using Hibernate API. However, one advantage this code offers is that it is now decoupled from Hibernate specific API. So in future if you want to migrate to another JPA implementation, you wouldn't have to change your code.

Comment: I am changing my existing hibernate session into JPA entity manager instances and  im changing all createCriteria query using suggested answer above, but i came across one statment like c.setCacheable(true) and c.setCacheRegion("generalCaache"), where c is Criteria instance(previously) which i have changed now to CriteriaQuery. What is the equivalent in the CriteriaQuery way ?